# DatePicker Com Datas Highlight

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou trabalhando com um calendário de eventos e gostaria que no calendário me mostrasse em cor diferente os dias que possuem eventos.

Uso o **datepicker**.
http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html

Estou procurando na documentação, mas não estou encontrando algo desse gênero que possa me ajudar. Terei que fazer uma pesquisa no banco via Ajax para pegar os dias que tem evento.

Terei que usar isso em alguma `option` ou `method` do calendário para comparar os dias e marcar a data que tenha evento, um `highlight`, por exemplo.

Meu código até o momento é esse, que funciona, só preciso implementar isso que estou falando.

### JS

```
$('#ui-calendar').datepicker({
        closeText: 'Fechar',
        prevText: 'Anterior',
        nextText: 'Próximo',
        currentText: 'Hoje',
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho', 'Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun', 'Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda-feira','Terça-feira','Quarta-feira','Quinta-feira','Sexta-feira','Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        todayHighlight: false,
        firstDay: 0,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: '',
        onSelect: function(dateText){
            var box = $('#treinamentos');
            var loa = $('.load');
            var err = $('.error');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                url: urlBase + '/select-treinamentos',
                data: { dataSelect : dateText},
                beforeSend: function(){
                    box.html('');
                    err.hide();
                    loa.show();
                },
                success: function(data){
                    loa.hide();
                    if(data.length == 0)
                        err.show();
                    else{
                        box.html('');
                        $.each(data, function(index, value){
                            box.append('<tr><td><span class="titulo">'+ value.titulo +'</span><span class="subtitulo">'+ value.subtitulo 
'</span><a href="'+urlBase+'/informacoes/'+value.id+'">MAIS INFORMAÇÕES</a></td></tr>');
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

### HTML

```
<div class="" id="ui-calendar"></div>

<div class="" id="ui-calendar"></div>
<div class="lista-treinamento">
    <span class="error">Não existem treinamentos para este dia.</span>
    <span class="load">Carregando Treinamentos...</span>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="treinamentos"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem um cara aqui que conseguiu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514772/highlight-certain-dates-on-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Consegui @PauloHDSousa. Eu dei uma lida nessa pergunta e achei outra semelhante.

Comment: Disponha @Zoom, fecha a pergunta entao

Comment: Não curto fechar perguntas.

Comment: Sem problemas, responde.

Comment: Não curto responder perguntas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui. Usando esse exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/o0o7u4k3/

Fiz a pesquisa no banco, gravei as datas no `array`. E na função `highlightDays` o `array` é percorrido comparando as datas do calendário e aplicando a classe `highlight` quando a data é igual.

Depois na função `datepicker`, chamo a opção `beforeShowDay: highlightDays`, com a função.

### JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: urlBase + '/all-treinamentos',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            datesTr.push(value.data);
        });
    }
});

function highlightDays(date){
    for (var i = 0; i < datesTr.length; i++){
        if (new Date(datesTr[i]).toString() == date.toString()){
            return [true, 'highlight'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}

$('#ui-calendar').datepicker({
    ...
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays
});
```

### CSS

```
table{
    tr{
       td{
             a{
                background-color: #000;
                color: #FFF!important;
             }
         }
    }
}
```